# Same DbContext shared for multiple HTTP requests

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac, dbcontext

I'm receiving the following exception when two concurrent requests are sent to my ASP.NET MVC web application. I simulated this by logging in from desktop and mobile at the same time.

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

I am using Autofac to register `DbContext`, `Repositories` and `Services`

```
builder.RegisterType<DbContext>().As<IDbContext>().Named<IDbContext>("appdb").InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<LogDbContext>().As<IDbContext>().Named<IDbContext>("applogdb").InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerRequest();
```

Services are also being registered to be created for every unique HTTP request.

```
builder.RegisterType<ProductService>().As<IProductService>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<CategoryService>().As<ICategoryService>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<ProductLineService>().As<IProductLineService>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<PatientService>().As<IPatientService>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<CommonService>().As<ICommonService>().InstancePerRequest();
```

My understanding is that I'm receiving the error because the same `DbContext` instance is being shared between the requests (root scope).

This does not make sense because I have registered my `DbContext` instance to create a unique instance for every HTTP request.

The only singleton object I have registered is the cache manager class.

Comment: Could this be because I have named my `DbContext` as 'appdb' and each request received the same instance? Edit= Doesn't have any impact

Comment: Can you please provide your connection string?

Comment: @StephenReindl `<add name="sqlserver" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.100.26;Initial Catalog=appdb;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=abc;Password=123;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=1;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=False" />`

Comment: I have researched about MultipleActiveDataSets and setting that to true will solve it. However, I still don't understand why I am receiving the error when DbContext is registered as `InstancePerRequest`.

Comment: The common cause is that EF is materializing a list of entities and lazy loading is triggered during that process. Also happens in single-threaded environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending 10 hours on thinking it was EF related, I decided to look at how I was resolving `IDbContext`.

The problem was I was not resolving `IDbContext` from the HTTP request container which is named 'AutofacWebRequest`. It was not creating an instance for every HTTP request, hence causing the error. This was a dependency injection related issue.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in your comment, please use `MultipleActiveDataSets = true` even if you set `InstancePerRequest`.

You are creating an instance per request for the `DbContext`, but the SQL server interface shares the same connection over several threads to reduce resource usage.

In addition, EF is sharing resources for lazy loading (see also @gert-arnold's comment)